# Does Postgresql has function LISTAGG(column_name [, delimiter] ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE )?

Tags: postgresql

It seems "ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE" feature is not available in Postgresql which goes with LISTAGG in Oracle. Is there a alternate function or workaround to it?

Comment: What should it do? I'm not an Oracle programmer, I have no idea.

Comment: The `on overflow truncate` in Oracle arises due to the 2000 byte string limit on varchar2 data types. This clause causes it to truncate the string to the limit instead of throwing an exception. Postgres has **no limit** on text data type. Therefore **no workaround is needed**, just use [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) in place of Listagg and forget about *on overflow*.

Comment: @Belayer, can we use string_agg instead of array_agg ?

Comment: Yes. `String_agg` returns a single string where as `array_agg` returns an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe array_agg / array_to_string is the Pg equivalent to Listagg:

```
select (array_to_string(array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], '-'))
```

Array_agg is the aggregate that creates the array from your result set.

And if you want to truncate an array, you can use the upper boundary (from the [lower:upper] syntax).  In this example, limit to the first six elements or truncate anything past the sixth in your terminology:

```
my_array[:6]
```

Combining these two, I believe you can do what you seek.  For example, if you have a field you want to concatenate with commas, but you only want the first 10 elements:

```
select
    array_to_string ((array_agg (my_field))[:10], '-')
from my_table
```